# Failed to login after setting fish as default shell

Tags: linux, shell, fish

I tried `fish` for a while, and then i wanted to set it as my default shell. I edited `/etc/passwd` and changed the shell of my user to `/bin/fish`.

The problem is I couldn't login anymore. I tried through my DM (SDDM), it said the login failed at any password I threw at it, correct or wrong. Then I tried it through a tty, got the same results. Replacing `fish` with the shell I had before in my `passwd` file seemed to fix this.

Is there any way to set `fish` as the default shell and still be able to login?

I am running Manjaro Linux.

Comment: Your primary mistake was editing */etc/passd* by hand. Had you used the appropriate command to change your login shell (e.g., `chsh`) it would/should have warned you about the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add this shell to `/etc/shells`. The [manual](https://linux.die.net/man/5/shells) reads:

> `/etc/shells` is a text file which contains the full pathnames of valid login shells. This file is consulted by `chsh(1)` and available to be queried by other programs.
>
> Be aware that there are programs which consult this file to find out if a user is a normal user; for example, FTP daemons traditionally disallow access to users with shells not included in this file.

In my Kubuntu this is the content of `/etc/shells`:

> ```
> # /etc/shells: valid login shells
> /bin/sh
> /bin/dash
> /bin/bash
> /bin/rbash
> /usr/bin/tmux
> /bin/zsh
> /usr/bin/zsh
> /usr/bin/fish
> /bin/tcsh
> /usr/bin/tcsh
> ```

As you can see its format is quite self-explanatory. In my case `fish` is there as `/usr/bin/fish`. Make sure the right path in your case is `/bin/fish` and add it to your file.

---

Note it's better to use [`chsh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh) to change your login shell, instead of editing `/etc/passwd` by hand. If you did

```
chsh -s /bin/fish
```

you would probably get

```
chsh: /bin/fish is an invalid shell
```

Investigating this issue (with [`man 1 chsh`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/chsh)) would probably reveal the existence of `/etc/shells` to you.

The tool is designed to be run by unprivileged users. If the content of `/etc/shells` (which is governed by root) is sane, then it's usually impossible for users to lock themselves out. By editing `/etc/passwd` you may not only lock yourself out like you did; you may (by mistake) break more.

Answer (score 1):

I believe Linux requires that all valid login shells be listed in `/etc/shells`. Add `fish` to that file before setting it as your login shell. Be sure to use its full correct path.